# php pdo statement error

Tags: php, pdo

I'm a newbie to php pdo. Here i'm trying to fetch my database records from database using prepared statements. But it didn't fetch the records. I'm getting this following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

why i'm getting this error? why it didn't fetch the records from database?

```
<?php
$user = "root";
$password = "password";

    try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;database=evouchers', $user, $password);
        $conn -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'DATABASE ERROR : ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT UserName FROM ebusers ORDER BY UserName";
    $db = $conn->query($sql);
    $db->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    while($row = $db->fetch())
    {
        print_r($row);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your db connection string instead of database use dbname

```
  $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;database=evouchers', $user, $password);
  ---------------------------------------^



 $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=evouchers', $user, $password);
```

Docs link: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: Thanks.. its working.. why we should use dbname in that place?

Comment: Every database system is a little different. Mysql just happens to use dbname.

Comment: it is requirement for PDO to use dbname for specifying databasename, you can see in the doc link.

Comment: now i'm getting the result like this Array ( [UserName] => Administrator ) Array ( [UserName] => Mr.Dependable ). if i want to fetch the Administrator, Mr.Dependable value means what should i do?

Comment: do it like echo $row['UserName']; you will get the value. let me know if any issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=evouchers', $user, $password);
```

Alternatively try just after you init PDO

```
$conn->exec('USE evouchers;');
```

Answer (score 2):

use the following line for pdo connection

```
 $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=evouchers', $user, $password);
```