# why is my php pdo statement inserting twice in the DB

Tags: php, android, sql, rest

i have an android app which is attempting to insert information to a database. i had a php REST API working perfectly fine WITHOUT PDO. i decided to try switching over to PDO prepared statements and i begun to experience some issues. i use to use mysql_query for inserting information to the database before i switched over to PDO. i have a feeling this is going to a be a very small and simple fix. please dont rip me too hard.

**what ive read**

[PDO Inserting twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774057/pdo-inserting-twice)

[PHP PDO statement error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987336/php-pdo-statement-error)

[URL rewrite with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182407/url-rewrite-with-htaccess-make-duplicate-mysql-entries)

**what ive done to debug**

1) i have only executed each statement once.

2) i have no rewrite rules in my .htaccess files :

```
# Do not remove this line or mod_rewrite rules and search engine friendly URLs will stop working
RewriteBase /
```

^^that is all thats in my htaccess file

3)  out of the two ($stmt and $sportStmt) i removed the second ($sportStmt) and the initial insert statement only inserted once, as desired.

4) i checked on my app side to see whether i was making a post request twice, but i wasnt. (also evident when i removed the second insert statement)

5) in case you are wondering if it is the table relations (pmk, fmk, triggers).. the script works perfectly fine before i decided to switch over to PDO prepared statements.

this is my code:

```
    <?PHP
include_once("connection2.php");

//prepare statement
    if (isset($_POST['sports'])){

    try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    switch ($_POST['sports']){
        case hockey:
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO hockey (name, age, league) 
                                VALUES (:name, :age, :league)");
        break;
        case soccer:
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO soccer (name, age, league) 
                                VALUES (:name, :age, :league)");
        break;
        case basketball:
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO basketball (name, age, league) 
                                VALUES (:name, :age, :league)");
        break;
        }

    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':age', $age);
    $stmt->bindParam(':league', $league);


    //insert Sport
    $playerSports = $_POST['sports'];
    $playerSports = trim($playerSports, '[]');
    $sports = explode(',', $playerSports);

    foreach ($sports as $value){
        $value = trim($value, ' ');
        switch($value){
            case hockey:
                $value = "hockey";
                break;
            case soccer;
                $value = "soccer";
                break;
            case basketball;
                $value = "basketball";
                break;
        }

        $sportStmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO playerSports (name, sports) VALUES (:name, :sports)
                                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name), sports = VALUES(sports);");
        $sportStmt->bindParam(':sports', $value);
        $sportStmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $sportStmt->execute();
    }


    echo "New records created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    } else {
        echo "did not receive category";
    }



$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: see typo error `case hocket:` also try to add defaults for your switches even if they don't do any thing

Comment: `$aoiStmt->execute();` should be `sport`?

Comment: @u_mulder yes sorry i forgot to change that when i switched over the fields to make it more understandable. i have corrected that

Comment: @BobbyAxe thank you for the default advice i will implement that immediately. that hocket was an error when i was switching over the names of the values for the sake of making this post easier to undestand. sorry for the type